Does secure bridge for ERC20 to Solana framework exist?
Looking to offer Solana bridge for my erc-20 token to users interested.
OFT LayerZero has been recommended, yet doesn't support Solana.
Wormhole is unsecure.
Any suggestions to bridge an ERC20 token to Solana?

LayerZero now supports Solana:
https://docs.layerzero.network/v2/developers/solana/oft/program
